# Extracting file names from text file after running tf history command

Tags: string, tfs, substring

I need some help. I have a text file and within it, I have an output from a TFS command (tfhistory):

---

Changeset: 74125
User: JDoe
Date: Thursday, August 30, 2012 3:56:06 PM

Comment:
  Task # 12345. JDoe.

Items:

merge, edit $/Project Name/FolderSln/Folder1/Binary.File1.cs

merge, edit $/Project Name/Folder1/Folder2/SQL_File2.sql

merge, edit $/Project Name/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File3.png

Check-in Notes:
  Code Reviewer:
  Performance Reviewer:
  Security Reviewer:

---

My objective is to filter all the junk from the file and only keep the list of files, in the example above, the output would be below. However, for CS files, we would be able to copy the dll instead of the file

---

Folder1.dll

SQL_File2.sql

File3.png

---

How can I achieve this considering there may be multiple change set sections with multiple files and file paths may be different?

I was thinking it would be possible to isolate the lines with a GREP or FINDSTR command to extract the file paths only, and then create a small application that uses an array to extract the file names and publish them to a different text file.

$/Project Name/Folder1/Binary.File1.cs

$/Project Name/Folder1/Folder2/SQL_File2.sql

$/Project Name/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File3.png

Answer (score 1):

assuming your output of tf history is in as file call tf.list, this batch will produce the desired result:

```
for /F "delims=$ tokens=1,*" %%a in (tf.list) do if NOT !%%b!==!! call :line "%%b"

goto :eof

:line
set filename=%~n1%~x1
echo %filename%
goto :eof
```